# Sequelize Query without Await keyword

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a some question about Sequelize query.

Below is some of my code to get some data from table.
I think it should not be working, because I did not add 'await' in front of 'SemeTable.fineOne(..'

But, the problem is... it is working. This function returns data.
I'm curious about how it is working. I tested other queries like findAll(), and it was working too.

From my understanding, most of query function of Sequelize are asynchronous. So, it will not return any data if I did not add 'await' keyword.

I tried to search this google, and Sqeulize official document, but I could not find any clues, or simular examples.

Is there any one who can explain what was happened.

Thanks in advance.

```
// The code that I think wrong. But, it is working. it returns data...

const SomeTable = require('../../model/some-table')


const getSomeResult = email => {

    const foo = SomeTable.findOne({
                where: { email: email }
            })

    return foo
}

-----------------------------------------------

// The code that I think correct

const SomeTable = require('../../model/some-table')


const getSomeResult = async email => {

    const foo = await SomeTable.findOne({
                where: { email: email }
            })

    return foo
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This first function returns a promise

```
const getSomeResult = email => {
    const foo = SomeTable.findOne({
                where: { email: email }
            });
    return foo // Type of food here is a Promise<SomeTable>
}
```

Then you must be resolving `getSomeResult(EMAIL)` somewhere else.

And for this one the second example, you are resolving your `findOne` promise inside the function and returning your data

```
const getSomeResult = async email => {
    const foo = await SomeTable.findOne({
                where: { email: email }
            })
    return foo
}
```

Simply and ugly example:

```js
function wait(milliseconds) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
}

async function myFunc(msg) {
  await wait(3000);

  return msg;
}


(async() => {
  const theResultPromise = myFunc("Hello!");

  console.log(theResultPromise instanceof Promise)

  console.log('The result:');
  const theResult = await theResultPromise;
  console.log(theResult)
  console.log(theResult instanceof Promise)

})()
```

Note that my `myFunc` just return a string, and not another promise so it's not a [`thenable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#thenables)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you said, I found that there was another function that call getSomeResult() using await keyword. That was why it worked. :) Thank you!